# ServiceWorker doesn't load matched resources

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am implementing a service worker on my web application.

This is my serviceWorker.js:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-cache';
var urlsToCache = [
    'img/logout.png'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
        }))
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log(event.request);
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }
    });
});
```

It's all woriking fine (in dev tools i can see the png file stored is the cache storage).
The problem is when i go offline: i guess that the get request for the png file is matched because if i navigate to `localhost:8080/myapp/img/logout.png` the response logged (as you can see in the script above) it'is not undefined but chrome still returns ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED.

This is the dir structure of the webapp:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SmOD.png)

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In `fetch` event of service worker Instead of matching request object change it to `cache.match(event.request.url).`